# Spark Scala replace Dataframe blank records to "0"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to replace my Dataframe field's blank records to "0"

Here is my code -->

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

case class CInspections (business_id:Int, score:String, date:String, type1:String)

val baseDir = "/FileStore/tables/484qrxx21488929011080/"
val raw_inspections = sc.textFile (s"$baseDir/inspections_plus.txt")
val raw_inspectionsmap = raw_inspections.map ( line => line.split ("\t"))
val raw_inspectionsRDD = raw_inspectionsmap.map ( raw_inspections => CInspections (raw_inspections(0).toInt,raw_inspections(1), raw_inspections(2),raw_inspections(3)))
val raw_inspectionsDF = raw_inspectionsRDD.toDF
raw_inspectionsDF.createOrReplaceTempView ("Inspections")
raw_inspectionsDF.printSchema
raw_inspectionsDF.show()
```

I am using case class and then converting to Dataframe. But I need "score" as Int as I have to perform some operations and sort it.
But if I declare it as score:Int then I am getting error for blank values.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

```
+-----------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|business_id|score|    date|               type1|
+-----------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|         10|     |20140807|Reinspection/Foll...|
|         10|   94|20140729|Routine - Unsched...|
|         10|     |20140124|Reinspection/Foll...|
|         10|   92|20140114|Routine - Unsched...|
|         10|   98|20121114|Routine - Unsched...|
|         10|     |20120920|Reinspection/Foll...|
|         17|     |20140425|Reinspection/Foll...|
+-----------+-----+--------+--------------------+
```

I need score field as Int because for the below query, it sort as String not Int and giving wrong result

```
sqlContext.sql("""select raw_inspectionsDF.score  from raw_inspectionsDF where score <>"" order by score""").show()

+-----+
|score|
+-----+
|  100|
|  100|
|  100|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty string can't be converted to Integer, you need to make the Score `nullable` so that if the field is missing, it is represented as null, you can try the following:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
```

1) Define a customized parse function which returns None, if the string can't be converted to an Int, in your case empty string;

```
def parseScore(s: String): Option[Int] = {
  Try(s.toInt) match {
    case Success(x) => Some(x)
    case Failure(x) => None
  }
}
```

2) Define the *score* field in your case class to be an `Option[Int]` type;

```
case class CInspections (business_id:Int, score: Option[Int], date:String, type1:String)

val raw_inspections = sc.textFile("test.csv")
val raw_inspectionsmap = raw_inspections.map(line => line.split("\t"))
```

3) Use the customized *parseScore* function to parse the score field;

```
val raw_inspectionsRDD = raw_inspectionsmap.map(raw_inspections => 
    CInspections(raw_inspections(0).toInt, parseScore(raw_inspections(1)), 
                 raw_inspections(2),raw_inspections(3)))

val raw_inspectionsDF = raw_inspectionsRDD.toDF
raw_inspectionsDF.createOrReplaceTempView ("Inspections")

raw_inspectionsDF.printSchema
//root
// |-- business_id: integer (nullable = false)
// |-- score: integer (nullable = true)
// |-- date: string (nullable = true)
// |-- type1: string (nullable = true)

raw_inspectionsDF.show()

+-----------+-----+----+-----+
|business_id|score|date|type1|
+-----------+-----+----+-----+
|          1| null|   a|    b|
|          2|    3|   s|    k|
+-----------+-----+----+-----+
```

4) After parsing the file correctly, you can easily replace null value with 0 using *na* functions *fill*:

```
raw_inspectionsDF.na.fill(0).show
+-----------+-----+----+-----+
|business_id|score|date|type1|
+-----------+-----+----+-----+
|          1|    0|   a|    b|
|          2|    3|   s|    k|
+-----------+-----+----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply! Its working now. :)

Comment: Can I write sql query inside sqlContext.sql as below? I am getting error for below query->

sqlContext.sql("""select CBusinesses.BUSINESS_ID,CBusinesses.name, CBusinesses.address, CBusinesses.city, CBusinesses.postal_code, CBusinesses.latitude, CBusinesses.longitude, Inspections_notnull.score  from CBusinesses, Inspections_notnull where Inspections_notnull.score <>0 and CBusinesses.BUSINESS_ID=Inspections_notnull.BUSINESS_ID """).show()


    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Don't really know the answer, but it seems you are trying to combine two tables, maybe you want a join?

Comment: Yes. I want to calculate Which 10 businesses got lowest scores?"
I have 2 tables-    "Businesss" and "inspections" with business_id common key. it works fine with sql but if I use the same query in spark, it doesn't work. How Can i join 2 tables with one column and calculate top score using Spark Sql?
I tried //val df = businessesDF.join(raw_inspectionsDF, businessesDF.col("BUSINESS_ID") == raw_inspectionsDF.col("BUSINESS_ID")) also but its also giving error